# how to move a bone to the opposite direction of the movement of another bone

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, pose-mode

I'm rigging train brakes. The vertical green bone is the Main Brake which I manipulate all bones. When I move the vertical green bone to right, all bones will move to right. But I want the number 2 (just number 2) moves to the opposite side like red arrow indicates.

How can I do that? Need more constraints?

Thanks for any help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just give bone 2 this constraint:

[image]

By checking "invert" it inverts the movement of your base bone.

Also check "offset" so that it keeps in place at it is.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer! thanks.